# Maven:Output Build log

Tags: maven-2

In Ant we have the provision to send the Build details to a log file by specifying the log file as a param while invoking the Ant build like ant -l $BUILDLOG
Do we have a similar functionality in Maven ?

Answer (score 6):

I added `> mvn_build_log.txt` to the end of my command to output the mvn build output.

Answer (score 5):

Not in maven 2. But it was added in maven 3 (currently in alpha) in the same form. e.g. `mvn -l $BUILDLOG`.